# What is the probability of this event?

Tags: probability

The question is: A card is drawn from an ordinary pack(52 cards) and a gambler bets that either a spade or an ace is going to appear. The probability of his winning are?
I think the answer is $\frac{16}{52} = \frac{4}{13}$. Did I go "probably" go wrong somewhere?

Comment: probably not wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 16 `good' cards (the 13 spades and the three other aces), out of 52 total, so you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you're correct! (Converting this to an answer.)

Comment: Beaten by a few seconds by Cheyne H!

Answer (score 0):

There are 13 spades that contain one ace and there are remaining three aces, thus there are altogether 16 choices for the bet and the probability = 16/52 and you are correct.